# How to keep header bar from cutting off while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, styling

I am just trying to format my header bar to not get cut off when the page can be scrolled from side to side, right now, if the window is too small, scrolling cuts the bar off at what the original page length was:

[image]

Here is the code as of now:

```
<div id="head-wrapper">
  <a href=<%=locations_path%>><img src= <%= asset_path('DL_Logo_CMYK.svg') %> id="header-logo" /></a>
  <div id="title">
     <a href=<%=locations_path%>>MapMail</a>
  </div>
  <div id="logged_in_message">
     <% if current_user %>
        <span id="username">Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>.</span>
        <span id="logout"><%= link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete %></span>
     <% else %>
       <span id="username">You are not signed in.</span>
     <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**application.css.scss**

```
.....
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: $font-color;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: GillSansMTBold, "Gill Sans", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  clear: both;
}

#content {
  margin: 20px;
}

.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.page-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

**_header.scss**

```
#head-wrapper {

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: $base-border-color;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: $medium-gray;
  padding: 5px;

  #title {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  #header-logo {
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
  }

  #logged_in_message {
    padding: 8px;
    float: right;

    #logout {
      padding-left: 10px;
    }

  }

}
```

I'm sure this is not super hard but I don't have a lot of css experience yet, so any help is really appreciated!

Comment: can you post your css please.

Comment: @Guy whoops, fixing now

Comment: how about `width: 100%` on your #header-wrapper? This will tell it to stretch to the size of its container whereas currently it is the width of the content within

Comment: @Guy no luck, actually seems to have made the header look clunkier when loaded in a small window and still gets cut off

Comment: Ah was a long shot! Hard to give any better help without seeing a working example. Any chance of a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is missing some quotes:  `<a href=<%=locations_path%>>MapMail</a>`  - it should be `<a href="<%=locations_path%>">MapMail</a>`, or, even better, `<%= link_to "MapMail", locations_path %>`

Comment: @Guy thanks for trying! and not really too sure how to get js fiddle to work with my code, I'll keep trying though, but there's no javascript going on behind the scenes right now for the header so you can pretty much see all code going into it

Comment: @MaxWilliams thanks for spotting that! will change it

Comment: Since this question doesn't really relate to your rails code at all, it would be helpful to see your rendered html (eg to use in a jsfiddle) - can you add that to your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say that any of these answers have helped me out so far, but I think I've gotten at least what I needed to looking some stuff up online.  Instead of adding code to the header I decided to add `overflow-x:scroll` to add a scroll bar to the information that was going of the screen before, eliminating my need to scroll the entire page.  I probably didnt give enough information about my page for people to suggest that so I am probably to blame for no right answers coming, thanks to everyone for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
html{
overflow:hidden;
}

#headerDiv{

width: 100%;

}
```

Edit:
Use JQUERY to fix the header when scrolling left/right !!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#header').css({
        'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + 0 //this will be according to the left Attr in css 
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so I can still allow scrolling? using this code fixes my problem but its more because I don't allow the user to scroll left and right anymore than an actual fix

Comment: you Can use width :100%; only .

Comment: that didn't work, scrolling still causes it to get cut off

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the confusing world of CSS positioning.  Like quantum physics, it's best to throw out all of your intuitive ideas about how things should work, and start with a blank slate.  Here's some links

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Edit - here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/37okrbzc/

There's extra styles added to enable the viewer to see what's happening.  it's only really the `position` rules which matter.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle demo.